# how to install nativeXML using Delphi 2009?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2009, nativexml

I`m using Delphi 2009 and want to operate some XML data. I heard that nativeXML is one of the most convenient ways to do it. so how can I install this library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NativeXML doesn't claim to support Delphi 2009 just yet. [Edit: Apparently there is a 2009 beta available to paying customers.]  The trial version does not, so it cannot work with Delphi 2009 until that version of Delphi is officially supported.

That said, using XML in Delphi for most purposes doesn't require third-party components.  You have several options, depending upon what you're doing.

1. The most straightforward is to use
   TXMLDocument.  This lets you open an
   XML file or stream, and access nodes
   using a DOM.
2. With the Enterprise version of
   Delphi, you get the XML data binding
   wizard.  This generates strongly
   typed mapping classes for a certain
   XML schema.  It's very convenient
   when you know exactly what the
   structure of the XML document you're
   parsing will be.
3. A third option is the XML mapper,
   which allows you to read XML data to
   and from a TClientDataset.

Comment: some internet-sources to be read how to use TXMLDocument? I tried but I can`t find the needed data(

Comment: Now it is open source, anyone can use it. I'm using it in Delphi XE FWIW.

Answer (score 4):

Based on their [web site](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html), it sounds like you just download the .dcu file, put it in a convenient directory, and add that directory to your type library path (tools->options->library path).

After that, just add the unit to your uses clause and you should be good to go.

Comment: If their site can be believed, they do not include Delphi 2009 DCUs (yet). D2007 DCUs won't work in D2009.

Comment: As a customer who paid for it, you should be able to download the beta version for D2009 from the private forum.

Comment: You are right... I forgot that D2007 and D2009 are not binary-compatible.